# C# WMI Query: How do I drill down farther into object type System.Management.ManagementBaseObject?

Tags: c#, powershell, wmi, wmi-query, wql

I am trying to programmatically query WMI for SAN WWN numbers on a database server. I am using WMI namespace root\wmi, and class MSFC_FibrePortHBAAttributes. My problem is that I can get to the Attributes property of this class, but I can not drill down farther into that property to obtain the `MSFC_FibrePortHBAAttributes.Attributes.PortWWN` value.

In PowerShell, the query is as follows (using an index as there are multiple):

```
PS C:\Users\e21013> (Get-WmiObject MSFC_FibrePortHBAAttributes -Namespace root\wmi)[0].attributes | select portwwn

    portwwn
    -------
    {99, 1, 1, 1...}
```

But, my task is to do this in C#. For example, in a related class, MSFC_FCAdapterHBAAttributes, I can query for HBA driver names with C# in the following manner:

```
// Special method to abstract out WMI queries in root\wmi namespace

// query is: "select * from MSFC_FCAdapterHBAAttributes"
        private void printSANData(String query)
        {
            ManagementScope scope = new ManagementScope(@"root\wmi");
            scope.Connect();
            List<PropertyData> valueList = new List<PropertyData>();
            SelectQuery selectQuery = new SelectQuery(query);
            ManagementObjectSearcher searcher = new                        
            ManagementObjectSearcher(scope, selectQuery);
            ManagementObjectCollection information = searcher.Get();

            try
            {
                foreach (ManagementObject obj in information)
                {
                    foreach (PropertyData property in obj.Properties)
                    {
                        if (property.Name.ToString().Equals("DriverName"))
                        {
                          string hbaDriver = "nothing";
                          hbaDriver = property.Value.ToString();
                          Console.WriteLine("DriverName: " + hbaDriver);
                        }
                    }
                 }
            }
            catch (ManagementException)
            {
                Console.Write("Server not SAN attached.");
            }
            searcher.Dispose();
        }
```

Which gives me: "DriverName: elxstor," a driver name. Cool.

However, when I want to use the same query logic and method to query the MSFC_FibrePortHBAAttributes class to query for `MSFC_FibrePortHBAAttributes.Attributes.portwwn`, I get stuck because Attributes is an `System.Management.ManagementBaseObject` and I can't figure out how to drill down farther into the object to get it's underlying properties.

If I try:

```
if (property.Name.ToString().Equals("Attributes"))
{
  string hbaAttribute = "nothing";
  hbaAttribute = property.Value.ToString();
  Console.WriteLine("Value: " + hbaAttribute);
}
```

I get: "Value: System.Management.ManagementBaseObject" and the property variable in the for loop does not have any members to go farther down the WMI path.

Any help is greatly appreciated. Let me know if any further clarification is needed, thanks.

Comment: have you tried to drill down the `property.Qualifiers`

Comment: Says it's a CIMTYPE. Not sure what to do what that, though.